# wildcards on executables (binaries)

Tags: file-format, wildcards

I can use wildcards to select certain types of files by their extensions, e.g.

```
mv *.cc src/
```

How to select executables that don't have an extension?

Comment: The 'file' command might be useful. For example: `
$ file /bin/bash
/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=63aef36943da49b10c68826319a6efcdc1744f8b, stripped
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This checks on the executable bit and will move all files in the directory you are in into `src/`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm +a=x -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} src/
```

This does not check what the filename is (so xxxx and xxxx.cc and anything else is moved as long as it is a "file" (`-type f`) the "x" (eXecute) permission is set (`-perm +a=x`)).

Comment: I think you need to place "and" between (is a "file") and (the "x" (eXecute) permission is set)

Comment: There's also a `-executable` flag in `find` and we can save the `xargs` with `find . -type f -executable -exec mv -t src/ {} +`

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK bash globs don't support that - but zsh does, via its *glob qualifiers*.

For example, the qualifier for executable plain files is (rather confusingly) `*` e.g.

```
ls -l *(*)
```

will list executable binaries and scripts. It doesn't yet provide a qualifier for binary files explicitly, however it does allow you to define your own as described in [zsh glob qualifier to exclude binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33051153/4440445) so for example you could do

```
mv -- *(*e:'file --brief --mime $REPLY | grep -q binary':) exec/
```

or define a helper function

```
binary() { file --brief --mime $REPLY | grep -q binary }
```

then

```
mv -- *(*+binary) exec/
```

(I added `--brief` to prevent possible false matches on the filename.)